# Why does data not save into pointer array?

Tags: c, double, scanf

I have a C code and wanna save data x and y but only I get a zero values into this pointer array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
    int n;
    //Ingreso el numero de puntos
    printf("Numeros de puntos: ");
    scanf("%i", &n);
    //Asignacion de memoria para los puntos x y y
    double *x= (double*) calloc(n,sizeof(*x));
    double *y= (double*) calloc(n,sizeof(*y));
    //Ingreso de datos 
    printf("Ingrese los puntos x,y: ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        scanf("%d", &y[i]);
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
        printf("\n%.3f, %.3f", *(x+j),*(y+j));
    }
    //Libero memoria de x y y
    free(x);
    free(y);
    return 0;

}
```

When I print anything with n numbers I get this n output (number of points equals 2)

```
0.000, 0.000
0.000, 0.000
```

Comment: When you use `scanf` you use `x[i]` and `y[i]`, but for `printf` you use `*(x + j)` and `*(y + j)`... Why this inconsistency? Pick one way and stick with it (I recommend array-indexing with e.g. `x[j]` and `y[j]`).

Comment: Also note that in C you [don't have to cast the result of `malloc` and its siblings (like `calloc`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I am learn pointers and I wanted to using differents ways to access  it.

Answer (score 3):

You have mismatch in the conversion specifier (`%d` - matching an integer and expecting the argument as pointer to integer) with the type of the argument (pointer to a `double`). This invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So, instead of

```
    scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    scanf("%d", &y[i]);
```

you should use

```
    scanf("%lf", &x[i]);
    scanf("%lf", &y[i]);
```